# accessing html inside of an iframe inside of another iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I'm trying to access the html inside of a second `<iframe>`. The layout looks similar to this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var j = window.frames['a'].window.frames['b'].document.body.innerHTML;
   alert(j);
</script>
```

And the html looks like this:

```
<iframe id="a">
    <iframe id="b">
        <span style="font-style:italic; font-weight:bold;">heyo!</span>
    </iframe>
</iframe>
```

But, whenever I try this, it doesn't work. Any ideas? Where am I messing up?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: I suppose you've just showed us a fragment of your actual HTML that doesn't really look as you've shown... Do all your frames display content from the same domain?

Comment: That is not valid HTML. An `iframe` will display a HTML document. The inner iframe will be ignored

Comment: You are confusing the *document* loaded into an iframe with the child nodes of the iframe element.

Comment: @Pekka — It is valid HTML. That is how you provide alternative content for browsers that don't support or have disabled iframes.

Comment: @Quentin: which brings us to the next nonsense. If iframes are disabled, then span will never exist since parent iframe won't be created, right?

Comment: @Cod-nerd: Which frame runs your script? top frame or any of the inner ones?

Comment: The weird thing is that it was working just a few days ago, no problem. But, now I don't know if I screwed something up somehow or now. It just stopped working. The original doesn't alert the html, it displays it in a `div`.

Comment: @RobertKoritnik — No, if iframes are disabled, then the iframe elements will be treated as any other "unrecognised element" and added to the DOM without special treatment.

Comment: @RobertKoritnik, This specific one is ran on the top frame right next to the parent iframe.

Comment: @Quentin true, true. But it won't do what the OP wants.

Comment: @Quentin: Ok. So we end up with something *arguably similar* to this, right: `<div id="a"><div id="b"><span...`

Comment: I just ran a test ([here](http://jsbin.com/evesod/1/edit)) which gives some very odd behaviour. My copy of Chrome appears to be treating iframes as elements that "can only contain text nodes" instead of creating a DOM inside them. If so, then to get the content of the inner iframe, you'd have to do a lot of reparsing of the HTML. Yuck.

Comment: @RobertKoritnik — Exactly.

Comment: This is not a valid HTML. if you will put your span, in another file, and put the path in the src of the iframe then you can get the data using the below code.

    var iframe = document.getElementById("b");
    var iframe_contents = iframe.contentDocument.body.innerHTML;
    alert(iframe_contents);

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
<iframe id="a" src="a.html">
</iframe>
```

Then on a.html:

```
<iframe id="b" src="b.html">
</iframe>
```

Then on b.html:

```
<span style="font-style:italic; font-weight:bold;">heyo!</span>
```